# javascript wont parse php html tags

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

php sends html strings to html via ajax wrapped in `<p class="select"></p>` tags, css reads class perfectly. javascript/jquery does not. javascript/jquery wont even parse `<p  onclick="function()"></p>`. What am i doing wrong?

**heres my php (sends data via ajax fine)**

```
echo "<p class='select' onclick='populate();' >{$row['song_name']} </p>";
```

**heres my css (works fine)**

```
p.select{color:#fff;padding: 5px;margin:0}
p.select:hover{color:#fff;background:#f60;cursor:pointer;}
```

**heres my javascript**
method 1 jquery.

```
$("p .select").click(function(){
        var str = $(this).val();
        alert(str);
  });
```

method 2 onclick function.

```
function populate()
{

alert('here')
}
```

neither of the two methods respond at all. Guru why is this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p .select").live ( "click" , function(){
        var str = $(this).text();
        alert(str);
  });
```

See

[Events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live)

> Binds a handler to an event (like
>   click) for all current - and future -
>   matched element.

Comment: Although as a P element doesn't have a value property, this still won't work: val() should probably be text(). http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

- `p .select` will choose `<p>` tags *containing* an element with class select. `p.select` selects `<p class="select">`.
- Why not move the `populate` function to within the live? I suspect the jquery live (or click) removes any explicit handlers.

Try this:

```
$("p.select").live("click",function()
{
    var str = $(this).text();
    alert(str);
    populate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a working(in Firefox) example below. I think you forgot to put the jquery method inside the onload event. Beside the other (small) bugs...

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         p.select{color:#fff;padding: 5px;margin:0}
         p.select:hover{color:#fff;background:#f60;cursor:pointer;}
      </style>      
      <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min(2).js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">         
         function bodyOnLoad() {
            //instead of "p .select" "p.select"
            $("p.select").click(
               function(){
                  //changed val() into text()
                  var str = $(this).text();
                  alert(str);
               }); 
         }
      </script>         
   </head>
   <body onload="bodyOnLoad()">
      <p class='select'>Songname</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery has a build in `$(document).ready(function(){...});` that is simpler than `<body onload="bodyOnLoad()>"`